# Wget HEAD request?

Tags: http, wget

I'd like to send the `HTTP HEAD` request using `wget`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's not wget, but you can do that quite easily by using curl.

```
curl -I http://www.superuser.com/
```

Produces this output:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently                        
Content-Length: 144                       
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8     
Location: http://superuser.com/
Date: Sat, 09 Oct 2010 19:11:50 GMT
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Comment: `-I` is equivalent to `--head`.

Comment: If you need self-signed certificate based `https`, you can also add `-k` or `--insecure`

Comment: Given that the question explicitly mentioned `wget` i can't understand why an answer using `curl` can be considered the best, especially that there may be contexts where just one of the two is available.

Comment: unfortunately, `curl -I` does not give the URL to where it is redirected when it's a 301 or 302

Answer (score 48):

Try:

```
wget -S --spider www.example.com
```

You can also pass `-O /dev/null` to prevent `wget` from writing HTTP response to a file.

Comment: `-S` will *show* headers, but it executes a `GET`, not a `HEAD`. In other words, it will fetch the entire URL.

Comment: `wget -S --spider http://localhost` log created in apache server is `127.0.0.1 - - [04/Mar/2014:15:36:32 +0100] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 314 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"`

Comment: from the manual : --spider          When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.

Comment: It is still creating an empty directory structure, so I found that `-nd` (`-nH --cut-dirs=100` also works) works to suppress that.

Comment: `-nv` or `--no-verbose` for just the facts.

Comment: You can also try the example on a very large remote file, it completes instantly, so it doesn't download it.

Answer (score 25):

There isn't any need for *curl*.

With Wget, adding `--spider` implies that you want to send a `HEAD` request (as opposed to `GET` or `POST`).

This is a great minimalistic way of checking if a URL responds or not. You can for example use this in scripted checks, and the `HEAD` operation will make sure you do not put any load on neither the network nor the target webserver.

Bonus information: If Wget gets an HTTP error 500 from the server when it performs the `HEAD` it will then move on to perform a `GET` against the same URL. I don't know the reasoning for this design. This is the reason why you may see both a `HEAD` *and* a `GET` request being performed against the server. If nothing is wrong then only a `HEAD` request is performed. You can disable this functionality with the `--tries` option to limit Wget to only one attempt.

All in all, I recommend this for testing if an URL is responding:

```bash
# This works in Bash and derivatives
wget_output=$(wget --spider --tries 1 $URL  2>&1)
wget_exit_code=$?

if [ $wget_exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
    # Something went wrong
    echo "$URL is not responding"
    echo "Output from wget: "
    echo "$wget_output"
else
    echo "Check succeeded: $URL is responding"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

`wget -S` gets file:

> Content-Length: 2316, Length: 2316 (2.3K) [text/plain], Saving to: `index.html'

`wget --spider` gets headers:

> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists., Length: unspecified [text/plain]
>   Remote file exists.

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu 19.10 Manpage: Wget](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/wget.1.html)

```
   --method=HTTP-Method
       For the purpose of RESTful scripting, Wget allows sending of other HTTP Methods
       without the need to explicitly set them using --header=Header-Line.  Wget will use
       whatever string is passed to it after --method as the HTTP Method to the server.
```

Used the following in my bash script and can confirm it works as expected!

```
wget --method=HEAD https://www.website.com/
```

Comment: At least the Wget version in Alpine Linux v3.12 does not support the `--method` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Though not `wget`, many `perl` installs with `lwp` module will have a `HEAD` command installed.